# Move last character of line to specific column -- sed? awk?

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I need to replace all lines ending with specific character (say, &) such that this character should be in certain column (say, 80).
Which tool is best?
I have started thinking about sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)&/\1 <what should be here??> &/'
```

but cannot understand how to replace with variable number of spaces such that & goes to column 80.
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is ill-defined. What happens to lines that are shorter than 80? Fill up with spaces? What happens to lines that are longer than 80? Is the 80th character replaced with `&`, or is `&` spliced into the position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `/e` switch to `s///` that tells Perl to **e**valuate the replacement portion to compute the result.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  s/^(.*)(&)$/$1 . " " x (79 - length $1) . $2/e;
  print;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ echo -e 'foo&\n&\nbar     &\nbaz' | ./align-ampersands
foo                                                                            &
                                                                               &
bar                                                                            &
baz
```

If your input contains TAB characters, you will need to use more sophisticated processing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but you can try something like (assuming your file is space delimited):

```
awk '/&$/ {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=(i==80)?"& "$i:$i}1' yourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk and Perl will both work. Both have `printf` and `substr`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "this is some text &";

my $last_char = substr($string, -1, 1);
$string =  substr ($string, 0, length ($string ) - 1);
printf qq(%-79.79s%s\n), $string, $last_char;
```

The `substr` command is available in both Awk and Perl.

The whole command could be made into a one liner:

```
printf qq(%-79.79s%s\n), substr ($string, 0, length ($string ) - 1), substr($string, -1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/&$/{$80="&"}1' file
```